# PWA migration to Ionic 4: iOS scrolling doesn't work

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I migrated an independent Angular PWA to be used in Ionic 4 as an hybrid app too. None of the Ionic markup is used in this PWA (ion-content, etc.). I also use original Angular router outlet. Everything works fine in Android, but in iOS scrolling is disabled.

Rendered structure:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <app-root>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <app-dashboard></app-dashboard> // Routed view
    <app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've managed to make scrolling work in iOS by applying this css changes:

```
html {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

The problem is that in the original pwa some views listen to window scroll events with `@HostListener('window:scroll', [])` in their processes and by applying this css hack the scroll is now in body and not in window.

Is there a way to fix window scrolling in iOS without having to refactor all the views to use ion-content markup?

Comment: hmm can you share more code around the part that is not working on iOS? template + ts code

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I've added the rendered structure. Ts in the view is irrelevant since you can build an empty component without logic and still the scrolling wont work.